# Passing an object to a dynamically created directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to do something simple, pass an object to a dynamically created directive. In short, I use a button directive which, on click, uses $compile to produce a template containing a directive element. I want to pass an object as this directive's attribute.

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('dirContainer')).append($compile("<my-dynamic-directive name='data.name' data='data'></my-dynamic-directive>")(scope));
```

fiddle works for Angular 1.2 but not for Angular 1.3! I can't find any relevant documentation for this change.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net//weso9huo/ (Angular dep in External Resources)

**EDIT** Fiddle is with 1.2. Changing it to 1.3 breaks it.

**EDIT 2** this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7jjfadun/ with Angular 1.3 doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've used Angular 1.2 in the fiddle. If you change the dependency to 1.3, it stops working

Comment: See my answer, You have not defined controller properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting following error

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/areq?p0=MainCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Angular 1.3+ no longer supports controller declaration on the global scope. **Apart from that your code works**.

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        id: 666,
        name: "Fabruce"
    }
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2pLw1y5c/)</kbd>

---

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        id: 666,
        name: "Fabruce"
    }
}

MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);
```

<kbd>[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/unz9kjm5/)</kbd>

Comment: Arrrrrgh, bitten by the out of scope in callback JS thing! Thx Satpal.